# How to make keyword for python script "python filename.py"

Tags: shell, cmd, terminal

I am trying to create an alias for `python filename.py` so I can use `my_keyword` to run my script file.

**Example:**

```
python filename.py
python filename.py
```

**Need to convert to**

```
my_keyword
```

So this will call my file.

Is it possible? If it is possible then How I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Linux, MacOS, or some other Unix-based environment, rename the file to `my_keyword` and use a shebang line to make it use the Python interpreter, and make the file executable. Then make sure the file is in a directory that's in your shell `PATH`.

```
mv filename.py my_keyword
chmod +x my_keyword
```

Make sure the first line of the file is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

This tells the shell to run Python and to interpret the contents of the file.

You may want to install the file in `/usr/local/bin`, or add `~/bin` to your `PATH`, so that you can execute the file without entering the full path.

Answer (score 1):

If you are on **UNIX** OS, you can make an `alias` for your `filename.py` with the keyword `my_keyword` and then you can easily execute from the terminal like below,

```
$ alias my_keyword="python ./filename.py"
$ my_keyword
```

**For Windows** : https://medium.com/@shivamethical/create-command-line-alias-in-windows-76684635b4c4

Comment: Sir, When I work it at local side at that time it works fine but when I try to use this in docker then not able to get the result.
Can you please suggest me solution in docker.

Comment: @AkshayJain the command above should work inside the docker container also. If you want this command in `Dockerfile` then this may help you: https://superuser.com/a/1209426

Answer (score 1):

For `macOS X Catalina`, you can do so via `alias`:

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `ls -la` to check whether you have `.zshrc`
3. If yes, and assuming the file is at a folder in your Desktop, you can simply type the following, do note that you need to swap `your_username` and `your_folder` accordingly.

`echo "alias key="python /Users/your_username/Desktop/your_folder/filename.py"" >> ~/.zshrc`

4. `source ~/.zshrc`

For macOS X before Catalina, replace `.zshrc` with `.bash_profile` from the instruction above.